# Sample size for comparing two properties of time series data

Tags: time-series, sampling, mean, sample-size, sample

I have a dataset of observations of two properties of an object (`x` and `y`), which are distributed over time, `t`:

```
|   t   |   x   |   y   |
-------------------------
|   1   |   5   |   A   |
|   1   |   4   |   A   |
|   1   |   5   |   A   |
|   1   |   6   |   B   |
|   1   |   10  |   A   |
|   2   |   3   |   A   |
|   2   |   7   |   A   |
|   2   |   2   |   A   |
|   2   |   8   |   B   |
|   2   |   9   |   A   |
```

This is just an example to show the structure of the dataset. In reality the dataset consists of several million rows. For each timestep `t` there are around 1000 observations of `x` and `y`. **Importantly**, within each timestep there is only one observation where `y = B`, the other observations all have `y = A`.

I want to compare the average value of `x` over the entire timeseries for `y = B` against values of `x` where `y = A`. However, for practical reasons it is not possible to retrieve all the values where `y = A`, so for each timestep I need to take a sample for comparison.

My question is therefore, how do I calculate the sample size to take at each timestep `t` to make a comparison? Or should the sample size be the same (i.e. 1 datapoint at each timestep `t`). A second question would be, how would this vary if we had several values of `y` within each timestep (but not the same amount in each timestep).

Thanks for any help or pointers in the right direction!